# What are the columns in bedtools coverage output hist file?

Tags: sequence-analysis, bedtools, coverage, exome

I am using [bedtools](https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#) to caculate the coverage of my targets of my WES data, to later plot. But to plot, I need to know what to plot and what it is I am seeing. I have unsuccefully tried to find what exactly the columns are in the output of the [bedtool coverage](https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/coverage.html#), and how to read them. Also, the documentation does not help me a lot, and I find it confusing. Does anyone know, or where to find this a bit more elaboratly explained?

I used the following code:

`bedtools coverage -hist -abam input.bam -b input.bed > output >2 log`

**Correction note**: the code above is actually wrong (thanks to @Alexlok) and should be:
`bedtools coverage -hist -a input.bed -b input.bam > output 2> log`

And the output is (first line):

[image: First 5 lines]

Last 5 lines:

[image: Last 5 Lines]

Thank you in advance

Comment: Make sure that you're not following a script written for bedtools version < 2.24: the inputs `a` and `b` are inverted in recent versions. So on a recent version of bedtools, if you want to count the read coverage of your features, you need: `bedtools coverage -a input.bed -b input.bam`. Your current command counts the number of features in `b` that intersect each read in `a`, and I'm not sure that what you want to do.

Comment: I am following workflows for exome coverage probally indeed using <2.24, since they were published a while ago... not finding any new versions. I want to see how much of the exome targets (bed file) are actually captured by my reads indeed. I use `-abam` (my aligned reads to the reference genome) and `-b` (my target bed file) option? So I am not actually using the `-a` option. Does it also count then? Thanks

Comment: If I understand correctly (I have only used bedtools a bit, no expert on that), on older versions (before 2.19.0) `-a` would have expected a bed file, so `-abam` made explicit that it was a bam. But on more recent versions, `-a` and `-b` automatically detect the input type, so `-abam` is synonym with `-a` (kept for compatibility). And since version 2.24 the options `a` and `b` are inverted, so you would need a `-bbam` (which does not exist since `-b` covers that use case). See the example in [the page you linked](https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/coverage.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for that. You are absolutly right and I got totally confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, it is an extended .bed file format, so not specific to bedtools output: [source bed file output](http://www.ensembl.org/info/website/upload/bed.html#optional).
With 4 added columns to the end from bedtools -hist option:
[bedtools -hist option](https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/coverage.html)

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer, appreciated.